# Sort css files by the color property

Tags: shell-script, sort, html

I would like to build script that sort the CSS file by colors.
For example:

```
.actions_menu_forgot_password_link:hover {color: #deca9b;}
.login_popup_forgot_password_link {color: #ddeffb;}
.login_popup_forgot_password_link:hover {color: #deca9b;}
.trading_data_allTrades_button {color: #ddeffb; }
```

Expected result:

```
.actions_menu_forgot_password_link:hover {color: #deca9b;}
.login_popup_forgot_password_link:hover {color: #deca9b;}
.login_popup_forgot_password_link {color: #ddeffb;}
.trading_data_allTrades_button {color: #ddeffb; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility may be, that you write an shell-script like this:

```
column  -s "#" -o "#" -t css.txt | sort -r -k2
```

This will first columnize your output and reverse-sort your lines on the second column.

Maybe a disadvantage is, that it modifies your code slightly (but not in a bad way) and definitely needs the hex-form of colors. With a notation like "color: blue" it won't work.

Comment: it dosnt work for me... :/ but thanx for tying.

Comment: what exactly is going wrong? can you provide more samples?

Answer (score 0):

With this input, you can simply tell sort to start sorting the line at the `#` character. Tell it that you have `#`-delimited fields and you want to use the second one as the sort key (or equivalently given that there's only one `#` per line, that you want to use all fields starting with the second one as the sort key).

```
sort -t '#' -k 2
```

If several properties have the same color, add the option `-s` to preserve the original order between properties with the same color. Alternatively, pass `-k 1,1` *after* `-k 2` to use the property name as the secondary sort key (note that any indentation is also included in this secondary sort key).

This should be good enough for your use case. If your real use case is more complex, you may need to massage the input before sorting it. To use `sort` to sort data where the sort key is not directly identifiable in the data, the general idea is to use line transformation tools such as sed or awk to make a copy of the sort key at the beginning of the line, then sort, and finally strip off the copied sort key. Here's the technique applied to this use case as an illustration, with an extra step of converting color names to hex values in the copied sort key (the original is unchanged).

```
sed 's/^.*color: *\([^;]*\);/\1;&/' |
sed 's/^black;/#000000;/; s/^red;/#ff0000;/; #etc.' |
sort |
sed 's/^[^;]*;//'
```